# Centoswebpanel roundcube 500 internal server error

Tags: centos7, roundcube, centos-web-panel

I have a digital ocean droplet in that I have installed Centos 7.5, and on that, I have installed CWP, with that there is some problem. the problem is that I have created the emails in that CWP when I try to login the Roundcube using that email then it redirects me to the blank page. and when I debug the round cube then I got one error in the network that when I enter the email id and password and click on the login then I saw the 500 internal server error in the post request of Roundcube.

I have also tried by deleting the emails from CWP and also checked by creating new emails but the errors remain, and also I have deleted the droplet and created the new droplet and tried doing so but the error still exists.

I have installed CWP el7-latest.

Error Logs

```js
[11-Feb-2019 07:13:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Net_IDNA2' not found in /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/bootstrap.php:405
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_utils.php(891): idn_to_ascii('localhost')
#1 /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_utils.php(869): rcube_utils::idn_convert('localhost', true)
#2 /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/program/include/rcmail.php(600): rcube_utils::idn_to_ascii('localhost')
#3 /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/index.php(109): rcmail->login('support@buywpte...', '', 'localhost', true)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/bootstrap.php on line 405
```

If anyone knows please help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the fix in 2021 here is what I used http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/index.php?topic=11376.0.

`curl -s -L https://www.mysterydata.com/upload/tmp/cwp_rc_fix.sh | bash`

Answer (score 0):

Run this SSH Command to update roundcube on your CWP

```
sh /scripts/mail_roundcube_update
```